# Grab next numbers in a string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Hi have a arraylist of String and it contains bunch of numbers and I have get the numbers in each "stage". And at but at the second stage it only grabs the 1 instead of 10 is there anyway I can grab the next integers in the string? I got it to work for any numbers less than 10 but after 10 it just goes off.

```
   int stage = 1; // depending on where it is placed in the program it changes
   String voteOne = "1 10 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2"; 
   char vote = voteOne.getCharAt(stage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
voteOne.split("\\s")
```

will return an array of Strings. Then Integer.parseInt() each of the strings. read the documentation of these 2 methods:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and then [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `Integer.parseInt(voteOne.split(" ")[stage])`

Comment: that'll resplit the entire string for each stage best to keep the result of split() as a reference somewhere